Why don't Gmail authentication headers match Authentication-Results
I am working on verifying the proper authentication (SPF, DKIM, and DMARC) of my SMTP setup.  I have noticed that in many cases when I view an emails headers in gmail (... > Show Original), the highlighted headers at the top might only show one of these authentication types. Below is an example image. Then, in the "Authentication-Results" printed below, all three authentication types are listed.  This discrepancy happens even if all three passed.  What determines whether or not an authentication method is highlighted at the top of the page?


You'll need to provide a concrete example. Your question is too broad and lacks detail. If Gmail isn't listing authentication information separate from the actual raw message, the first step would be reviewing your raw message and your configuration. If you want to better understand your email deliverability then see this answer I wrote recently about about Google Postmaster Tools, also see Google's Message Header analyzer

@Blindspots I added a screenshot example.  Thank you for the links; the header analyzer confirmed that all three methods passed.  I still don't understand why the upper portion of the gmail page sometimes shows all 3, sometimes 2, sometimes 1.

Thanks for the screenshot and validating the headers. Great attitude! This is a bit out of site scope but since you're being helpful let's see if  we can get to the bottom of it, and then tweak your question to  be more clearly on-topic. Can you now post an example of a  header that successfully returned  2 but should have been 3, and another with 3 of 3? I assume the tool that highlights this is not the same tool that actually validates it. Comparing the raw headers might provide a clue to why this tool is missing the content if it's simply scanning the text strings and not really validating.
